# .htaccess: redirect if file doesn't exists

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, yii2

It is quite popular question, but there is some distinction in my case that makes all more difficult.

Apache2 web server, Yii2 framework with prettyUrl turned on.

Here is initial `.htaccess` file, provided by Yii2:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

There is `/docs` web directory. And I would like to get files from it if they are exist and redirect to `/docs-generator/create?file=<file_name>` if the file doesn't exists.

So, I have added a rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/docs
RewriteRule ^docs/([\w-_.]+) http://kz_proj.test/docs-generator/create?file=$1 [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

It's works but quite strange... First of all, I can't remove my test hostname from `http://kz_proj.test/docs-generator/create?file=$1`. It doesn't work without full name. The second one is about `^/docs` and `^docs/([\w-_.]+)` without the leading character. Why first part of these rules can't be the same in my case?

I guess something wrong with the rules...

Comment: why don't use 404 redirect ???

Comment: Due to I generate content inside the script and pass it to a user anyway (exists the file or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^docs/([\w-_.]+) /docs-generator/create?file=$1 [L,R=301]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

It works with the domain name because it is necessarily a redirect in this case, but not without. I added `[R=301]` to force the redirection.

No need to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/docs`
because the test is the same with `RewriteRule ^docs`

And why first part of these rules can't be the same in your case ?
`REQUEST_URI` always start with a `/`
and `RewriteRule test path` never start with a `/` in .htaccess (why????)

Comment: Great, it works for me! To chain a few such rules I should add new `RewriteCond + RewriteRule` statements or just `RewriteRule` with new `test path` part?

Comment: Glad to know it worked out. You need to add `RewriteCond + RewriteRule` because `RewriteCond` only works for the next `RewriteRule`. Or you can add RewriteCond rule to exclude others after, with `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`